# Values with "." are not imported from excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an excel file which looks like this:

[image: excel file in png]

Each time my file includes a line like this: `2   1.258   4.587   6.325`, my code does not read numbers with `.` or `,` and for the given line, only `2` is imported.

Here is my code (which works well but not when my file includes decimal values):

```
Xtrain1 = xlsread('mma_kag\train1.xlsx','B:F');
```

The error is:

> dimension of datapoints must be larger than 0

This means that it does not read the file and I have checked it. It was `[]`.
How to fix this problem?

Here is the [**link**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_6RXQUqktUOV0NSWE93SWNKYWs?usp=sharing) of the excel file.

Comment: Can you upload or provided the excel document? Also the question has nothing to do with svm.

Comment: @Mikhail I have added the excel file ( a screenshot ) because I dont know how to load the file here

Comment: just upload the file

Comment: I am not able to do it maybe it needs particular reputation !! as in voting I am new here !any way I dont find how to upload it  but I have added a figure of my excel file to the description !

Comment: It is at the end of the question's description just click on "here is what the excel file include"

Comment: Your error is not reproducible. Provide (an example)  of the actual file that produces the error. Upload it somewhere (Google Drive, One drive etc) and provide the link

Comment: here is the link         [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_6RXQUqktUOV0NSWE93SWNKYWs?usp=sharing)

Comment: ok let me try .

Comment: @SardarUsama thank you I am grateful for your time and consideration, and soory since I am new here and  I missed lot of things... thank you for Mikhail as well :)

Comment: thank you thank you I have been stuck for hours thank you , am waiting @SardarUsama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers in your cells are considered as text and hence the error. It has nothing to do with numbers being not integers. There are two approaches to solve this error.

**Excel Approach**:

- Select all the cells (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
- Then click on [image: this]. This will open a dropdown menu.
- Now select *Convert to Number*.
- Save the excel file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).  (Keep a copy of the previous one if you need that)

[image: excel approach]

For details on this, read this topic:

 ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ [Fix text-formatted numbers by applying a number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-text-formatted-numbers-by-applying-a-number-format-6599c03a-954d-4d83-b78a-23af2c8845d0)

---

**MATLAB Approach:** 

Use [the third output of `xlsread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbmn) and convert the text into double like this:

```
[~, ~, Xtrain1] = xlsread('mma_kag\train1.xlsx','B:F');
Xtrain1 = str2double(Xtrain1); %Converting the strings in the cell to double
```

**Edit:**
If your file has numbers as texts scattered arbitrarily (as in the new file that you uploaded), you would need first and third outputs of `xlsread`. Something like the following would do:

```
[tmp,~, Xtrain1] = xlsread('train1.xlsx'); %Select the range as per your need if necessary
Xtrain1 = str2double(Xtrain1);       
%Above line will convert the text into numbers and the numbers will be converted to NaNs 
Xtrain1(isnan(Xtrain1))=tmp(~isnan(tmp));  
%Above line retrieves the numbers from `tmp` & stores them in `Xtrain1`
```